# VideoView "can't play the video" error

Tags: android, video

here is [my video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8uvtc38p2k6b8t/2016-05-09-11%3A11%3A26.mp4?dl=0), i can play this video on any player except VideoView(but I can play it with MediaPlayer#setDataSource), here is my code:

```
    VideoView vp = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.player);
    vp.setVideoPath("/sdcard/videoRecorder/2016-05-09-10:31:42.mp4");
```

the monitor only provide "unknown error" like

```
05-09 11:22:53.173 4667-4683/ro.adr.test E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
05-09 11:22:53.339 4667-4667/ro.adr.test E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

I hope find a way use **VideoView** play this video, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the file name looks suspicious. Could you try changing it to a standard one to test again? i.e. without ":"

You can still use setVideoPath(string path), but need to make sure the path is a uriString. Below is the actual implementation of this method in Android. You need to encode your string first before passing in.

```
public void setVideoPath(String path) {
    setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
}
```

uri reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html

Comment: you're right, when i rename it to test.mp4, it work, VideoView is so stupid, can you tell me more common way, i mean make VideoView can play video that path include ":"